# Use enumerations extension methods to shorten code

Tags: c#

I want to checkmark some listview items from a given array. How could the code below be shortend with enumeration extension methods.

```
    foreach (Team SelectedTeam in value.Teams)
    {
       foreach (ListViewItem LVItem in TeamLstVw.Items)
       {
          Team Team = (Team)LVItem.Tag;

          if (SelectedTeam.Equals(Team))
             LVItem.Selected = true;
       }
    }
```

Comment: you want to do what?

Comment: You're asking us to write code for you? Try it yourself, and if you encounter any concrete problems, come back, edit your question with a description and an example of the problem an we try help you.

Comment: Start reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq) of Linq.

Comment: I want to select some list view items in a list view item control with a checkmark from a set property. The setter delivers an array so that matching list view items are checkmarked.

Comment: Oh, so we got lost in translation here. You  want to set `Selected == true` or just "tick" a checkbox. I was too stupid to infer that from your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could eradicate the outer foreach loop, by using Linq methods inside the inner foreach loop. In this case, you could just check if the current `LVItem.Tag` is contained inside `value.Teams`

```
foreach (ListViewItem LVItem in TeamLstVw.Items)
{
    var Team = (Team)LVItem.Tag;
    //I'd personally compare an identifier here. Like an Id property
    //.Any(x => x.Id == Team.Id)
    //Or use .Contains(): value.Teams.Contains(Team)
    if(value.Teams.Any(x => x == Team)) {
        LVItem.Selected = true;
    }
}
```